# How to find the accounts that do not exist in the Account database using SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql

If I have a list ‘My_list’ that has a bunch of account[company] names,

Using one SOQL How do I find the account names in ‘My_list’ that do not exist in Account database?

The code below shows how i save the Accounts that are in my list:

```
  u = [SELECT Email,FirstName, LastName, Company, FROM Lead  WHERE User_Processed__c = False];
  Set<String> My_list= new Set<String>();
  List<Lead> lList = u;
        for (Lead l : lList) {
          My_list.add(l.company);         
        }

list<Account> AccountList = [select id, name from Account where name IN :My_list];
```

The AccountList will show only the companies that exist in My_list,

How do i query the Accounts that do not exist?

In other words, how do i find a list of leads, that do not match any company in my org?

Comment: Ok i have updated the question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to use `NOT IN:` instead of `IN:`

```
list<Account> AccountList = [select id, name from Account where name NOT IN :My_list];
```

Check out these Comparison Operators for some more info

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

> **EDIT**

So if you want to know which of the leads in your list does not match an account in your org, code below should work.  The one caveat being that this is querying for all accounts and also for all open leads.  This could cause some issue if you are in an org with large amounts of data.  So I would recommend trying to filter the queries to cut down on the number of records.  Other than that it should work

```
//Add some sort of filter to ensure you don't go over 50k records
  list<Account> AccountList = [select id, name from Account];

  Set<String> accountSet= new Set<String>();
  for (Account a : AccountList) {
     accountSet.add(a.Name);         
  }
  List<Lead> lList = leadsWithNoMatch = new List<Lead>();
  for(Lead l : [SELECT Email,FirstName, LastName, Company, FROM Lead  WHERE User_Processed__c = False]){
     if(!accountSet.contains(l.company)){
        leadsWithNoMatch.add(l);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve null if the account doesnt exist, i mean how can i query, to get both values and null's in the AccountList?

Comment: I guess I dont understand what you are asking.  If you use this method, you will get a list of all accounts in your org that dont have a name that matches a name from your list of leads.  Isn't that what you were asking for in your question?

Comment: Well actually the code you gave me is not returning anything, I guess im confused how will the AccountList return anything from the Account if it doesnt exist?

Comment: You arent trying to find accounts that dont exist.  you are trying to find all accounts that dont match the leads in your list.  If you are getting no accounts returned, then this would suggest you are using a list of leads that have the same company names as all accounts in your org.

Comment: If you are trying to find a list of leads, that do not match any comapny in your org, you would have to do something different.  Is that what you are trying to accomplish?  Of your list of leads, which ones dont have a match?

Comment: Yes, yes, thats it, sorry if i was unclear about that

Comment: Edited answer.  Try that out

Comment: SO to be honest with you i had a similar loop, but i'm worried about processing Bulk leads, is 500 Leads considered a bulk?

Comment: Shouldnt be an issue.  Its utilizing Sets, no SOQL in loops, adding matching leads to a list that can be acted upon in a single DML.  Should be ok